# Can anyone tell me any SMTP server i can use to send an email from my php page?

Tags: php, smtp

i also want know how to authenticate and use Google SMTP server.

Answer (score 2):

Use gmail with these settings:

**smtp: smtp.gmail.com

port : 587

user: your gmail email address

pass: your gmail password**

You can use [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) amongst others to send your email from your page.

Comment: i did as u said but it didnt work i need help in setting up the php.ini and php coding.
can u please help pme with this matter and tell me if how can i use ptcl smtp server.

i did the following changes

[mail function];
 For Win32 only.; 
http://php.net/smtp
SMTP =smtp.gmail.com; 
http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 587; 
For Win32 only.; 
http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = hamza.yahoom@gmail.com
auth username:hamza.yahoom@gmail.com
auth password:example

Comment: @Rookie9:You should post your complete code to see how you are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your host. Your host should hae a SMTP server for you. SMTP sending is a standard operation for a web host.

For authentiaatio nagainst google, ask google. There must be a webpage about sending emails via PHP and google - not using PHP here, so I can not answer that.